# Nuget Package Manager for Visual Studio 2012 not opening at all

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package, nugetgallery

I have been trying to find a solution for this since almost 3 days, but i'm stuck and cant figure out why the **Nuget** **package** **manager** is just not opening, it does not even give any error.

Things i have tried so far:

- Uninstalled and re-installed the **nuget** **package** **manager** from within **VS 2012** but it didnt work
- Uninstalled and re-installed **Visual Studio 2012** and then tried the above step once again, but still nothing happened.

When i navigate to **Tools -> Library Package Manager ->** and click on all the options listed in it, nothing opens, no sign of any error etc.

Can someone please help me with a workaround for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download and install it from 
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c
or 
https://nuget.codeplex.com/downloads/get/784776

Comment: Thanks a ton man !! Was unaware of the standalone installers, i used the codeplex link and it worked! Thanks once again.. Much Appreciated!